# Is it Posible to start docker on Virtual Machine?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I want to install Docker Desktop on my Virtual Machine. The specification of VM Window 10 Pro. 64 bit Processor.8 GB ram. The installation complete successfully but it not starting the application. I have check the hyper-V is check. I try different method but it still not working. NEED Help

Answer (score 1):

Actually when using Docker Desktop on Windows or on macOS the `docker` daemon already is running in a VM since `docker` / containers are based on namespaces in the Linux Kernel.

But this means that "running Docker Desktop on a Windows VM" would require to start a Linux VM (which is the actual `docker` host) *inside* the Windows VM! For this to work you need to have a working setup for *nested virtualization* to allow starting a VM inside a VM.

This is not officially supported by `docker`, see [*Running Docker Desktop in nested virtualization scenarios*](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#running-docker-desktop-in-nested-virtualization-scenarios).

Another approach you could try though is to manually a Linux VM next to the Windows VM, i.e. on the same hardware host you are running the Windows VM on, and connect with the `docker` command from your Windows VM to the `docker` VM, see [`DOCKER_HOST`](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api).

But in this setup having volumes on the Windows VM and port forwarding working requires some more manual steps...